# Is there a way I can get a top level application in ActionScript?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, static, adobe

Is there a way I can get a top level application in ActionScript like you can in Flex?

example:

```
mx.core.FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless you hold it somewhere as a static, or do something convoluted like get the stage reference and go through it's children until you find your Main class

Comment: Alright, I figured out that you can do it statically, thanks for the info. :D